# Rotating & Scaling a Sprite image in COCOS2D Android

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, rotation, scale

I am using COCOS2D for Android. I want to rotate a rectangular sprite and scale it to different heights, but two of its vertices being at a fixed place. I mean, out of four vertices of a rectangle, I want only two vertices to move to different points and even scale the rectangle to varying length.
Similar example for varying length: Thermometer,where rectangular mercury level goes up & down fixing two vertices at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this, move your `anchorPoint` to the edge that you wish to remain constant. Lets say you move your `anchorPoint` to the bottom edge of your thermometer sprite, when you scale it, only the top edge will move. The `anchorPoint` has a float value of 0..1 corresponding to 0-100% of the sprites dimensions.

Please note, this will affect your `position` to you may need to adjust by 1/2 of the sprites width (or height, depending on how you set it up). The `anchorPoint` of your sprite resides where your sprite's `position` is. So by default, the `anchorPoint` is located at (0.5, 0.5) which is why your sprite is centered wherever you position it. If you were to alter the `anchorPoint` to (0.5, 0) then the sprite would be centered horizontally, but the bottom of the sprite would align with wherever you set its `position` to be, and it would scale away from the anchor point.

These links will also prove to be invaluable to you:

http://www.qcmat.com/understanding-anchorpoint-in-cocos2d/

http://cocos2d-central.com/topic/436-position-vs-anchorpoint/

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/1557

Comment: Best of luck to you with your application =]